# How to add object in treeview from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, treeview

I have a multithreading app, and I need to add object from another thread to the treeview. But I keep getting an exception

> Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action.

Here is my code

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(GetFiles), entryPoint);

private void GetFiles(object entryPoint) 
{ 
      var localData = entryPoint as EntryPoint; 
      this.GetFiles(localData.DirectoryInfo, localData.TreeNode); 
      localData.ManualEvent.Set(); 
}

private void GetFiles(DirectoryInfo directory, TreeNode tree) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.GetLength(0); i++) 
    { 
        tree.Nodes.Add(allFiles[i].Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a standard message, You cannot modify elements created by the UI-thread from a non ui thread. Use BeginInvoke() with an anonymous delegate or an usual delegate on the mainform from Your thread. I think, lambda and linq even offer better methods.

Comment: i doing with a help of delegate, but still recieve an exception public delegate void MyDelagate(TreeNode tree, string value); 
public MyDelagate TreeViewDelegate;
TreeViewDelegate = delegate(TreeNode tree, string s) 
{ 
tree.Nodes.Add(s); 
};TreeViewDelegate.Invoke(tree,allFiles[i].Name);

Comment: IMHO you don't need to use `ThreadPool` at all. Just call the method in UI thread. Your method isn't doing any significant work.

Comment: Read the exception message, the answer is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, you need to perform UI related actions on the UI thread. In order to do this, you can use `BeginInvoke` from the control itself.

```
private void GetFiles(DirectoryInfo directory, TreeNode tree) 
{ 
    if (TreeViewControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        TreeViewControl.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.GetLength(0); i++) 
            { 
                tree.Nodes.Add(allFiles[i].Name);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to do this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => GetFiles(directory, tree)));
```